# How can i create a roll dice button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a roll dice button for my code but I'm not quite sure how I can do this, since if I do create one then either it does not work how I want it too or my button does not function right.

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="Default Styles"/>
    <script>

      var r_text = new Array ();
      r_text[0] = "All leave are brown";
      r_text[1] = "fafwfaf";
      r_text[2] = "fakfjwkfkajwkfawjf";
      r_text[3] = "cornflakes";
      r_text[4] = "bannana";
      r_text[5] = "Choclate";
      r_text[6] = "lol";
      var i = Math.floor(7*Math.random())



      var videos = [
   {
      id: 1,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ngUMyF9D9SQ?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/v=r-l_gVPVylM?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ukTzRjXcR0?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 4,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/n5BXMNCTu8I?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 5,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JtwVmnMNaEY?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 6,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/lAMgRaHP8Q4?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   }

];

window.onload = function() {
   var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
   var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
   var previousId = localStorage.getItem("previousId");
   if (previousId) {
      var previousIndex = videos.findIndex(v => v.id === parseInt(previousId));
      videos.splice(previousIndex, 1);
   }
   var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
   localStorage.setItem("previousId", videos[current].id);
   localStorage.getItem("previousId");
   var randomVideoUrl = videos[current].url;
   player.setAttribute("width", "640");
   player.setAttribute("height", "390");
   player.setAttribute("src", randomVideoUrl);
   playerDiv.appendChild(player);
   var textContainer = document.getElementById("r_text");
   setTimeout(() => {
    textContainer.innerHTML = videos[current].text;

    }, 3000)
};




    </script>
</head>


<div id="random_player">
  <div id="r_text">
  </div>
</div>


</html>
```

I am expecting it to have nothing at first apart from the button and once the button is clicked then the video starts playing and then everything else starts to happen.

Comment: There is no button in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://codepen.io/dsb/pen/XWrQbxR

Explanation:
1) Add button to HTML

```
<button id="btn-roll">Roll</button>
```

2) Modify JS code

```
var r_text = [];
r_text[0] = "All leave are brown";
r_text[1] = "fafwfaf";
r_text[2] = "fakfjwkfkajwkfawjf";
r_text[3] = "cornflakes";
r_text[4] = "bannana";
r_text[5] = "Choclate";
r_text[6] = "lol";
var i = Math.floor(6 * Math.random())

var videos = [{
    id: 1,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ngUMyF9D9SQ?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[1]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/v=r-l_gVPVylM?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[2]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ukTzRjXcR0?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[3]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/n5BXMNCTu8I?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[4]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JtwVmnMNaEY?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[5]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/lAMgRaHP8Q4?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[6]
  }

];

window.onload = function() {
  function rollVideo(numberRand) {
    let playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
    if (document.querySelector("iframe") !== null) {
      document.querySelector("iframe").remove();
    }
    let player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    let randomVideoUrl = videos[numberRand].url;
    player.setAttribute("width", "640");
    player.setAttribute("height", "390");
    player.setAttribute("src", randomVideoUrl);
    playerDiv.appendChild(player);
    document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = videos[numberRand].text;
  }
  startRoll(i);

  document.getElementById("btn-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);

  function startRoll() {
    let currentNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    rollVideo(currentNumber);
  }
};
```

There is no conditions about text variables and id of previous video so i minified the example.

Comment: I think `var i = Math.floor(6 * Math.random());` should be `var i = Math.floor(7 * Math.random());` or even `var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random())`

Comment: That is what i wanted but how can i not have the video playing from the start and only showing the roll dice button first and only first.

Comment: @TauheedAhmad Remove `startRoll(i);` then. While you are at it, you can comment out `var i = Math.floor(6 * Math.random());` which is wrong anyway as I said before. Also note that `startRoll` does not have a parameter.

Comment: I tried to add this to my code but its not working at all are you able to use this with the code i have currently as it is.

Comment: In what way is it failing? It is working on codepen as linked.

Comment: But on codepen the whole code is different which i dont want i only want the start button roll and that only shows first and then when you click it then the video starts playing ect..

Comment: Well see my comment about `startRoll(i);` removal

Comment: I did that but the thing is when i put it in my code and pressed the roll dice button nothing happened and im thinking that is because i have no changed my whole code which i do not want to do anyway.

Comment: @Adder video links were taken from the task.

Comment: @TauheedAhmad Bro, we can help with the code and conditions that you showed us. But we can't do it if we didnt see another parts of your app.

Comment: @TauheedAhmad Your code has some issues which prevent a simple solution like uncommenting a line. The r_text isn't used right. There is code that removes the previous_Id from the list of videos, so that you cannot reroll the same video, which is a feature that is not obvious that you want it. I would recommend you use krolovolks code.

Comment: That is the only part tho apart from some css which is only to do with customizing the text but the real code is the one ive showed.

Comment: I'm only asking for the start button nothing more than that or optimizing any code i just want a start roll dice button that works with the code that i already have, unless it will not work completely.

Comment: @TauheedAhmad create working part of your code on codepen or jsfiddle or restructure your task. And we'll try to help you

Comment: The working part of the code is what i have already put and the problem im having is where i tried your demonstration on the code i have but when i click the button nothing happens and plus the video starts playing first even before i click anything and i do not have the startroll(i); in there aswell.

Comment: No i am saying that i added your button to my code but it is not working right.

Comment: The one that you made you have made some certain changes that does not have random text anymore but i still want the random text to be displayed since your one is static text e.g. it is fixed for that specific video but i want the text to be random and that is why im having the issue with butting the button in my code which works with the code i have currently.

Comment: So initially i would like the button to work with the code i already have since i need random text to be displayed as well as random video to be displayed and not playing the previous video that is all i asked for which was the button to work.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see i have added your code but nothing happens.

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="Default Styles"/>
    <script>

      var r_text = new Array ();
      r_text[0] = "All leave are brown";
      r_text[1] = "fafwfaf";
      r_text[2] = "fakfjwkfkajwkfawjf";
      r_text[3] = "cornflakes";
      r_text[4] = "bannana";
      r_text[5] = "Choclate";
      r_text[6] = "lol";
      var i = Math.floor(7*Math.random())



      var videos = [
   {
      id: 1,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ngUMyF9D9SQ?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/v=r-l_gVPVylM?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ukTzRjXcR0?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 4,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/n5BXMNCTu8I?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 5,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JtwVmnMNaEY?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   },
   {
      id: 6,
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/lAMgRaHP8Q4?autoplay=1",
      text: r_text[i]
   }

];

window.onload = function() {
  function rollVideo(numberRand) {
   var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
   var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
   var previousId = localStorage.getItem("previousId");
   if (previousId) {
      var previousIndex = videos.findIndex(v => v.id === parseInt(previousId));
      videos.splice(previousIndex, 1);
   }}
   var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
   localStorage.setItem("previousId", videos[current].id);
   localStorage.getItem("previousId");
   var randomVideoUrl = videos[current].url;
   player.setAttribute("width", "640");
   player.setAttribute("height", "390");
   player.setAttribute("src", randomVideoUrl);
   playerDiv.appendChild(player);
   var textContainer = document.getElementById("r_text");
   setTimeout(() => {
    textContainer.innerHTML = videos[current].text;

    }, 3000)
};

  document.getElementById("btn-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);

    function startRoll() {
      let currentNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
      rollVideo(currentNumber);
    }





    </script>
</head>


<div id="random_player">
  <div id="r_text">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn-roll">Roll</button>

</html>
```

Comment: When you click the roll button nothing shows up or anything and im not sure why?